# JSON.parse - Set reviver once for all

Tags: javascript, json, angular

In my Angular 2 application I need to parse some JSON strings that contain old ASP.NET dates, for instance `/Date(1497984415000-0500)/` (I receive them from a WCF service).

I know I can use **JSON.parse** with a [reviver parameter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjxtasg4bVAhXMLlAKHVm_CwIQygQILzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fit%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse%23Using_the_reviver_parameter&usg=AFQjCNHG1JnNu0MmnjC4rHXM2mgRDE115Q), but I need to do that many times in many pages of my web application so I would like to set the reviver once for all.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with sending all functions with pipe function like this.

```
 postMethods(url:any,data:any) :Observable<Response>{

       let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');  

      return this.http.post(`${API_URL+url}`,JSON.stringify(data),{headers:headers})
            .map((res:Response)=>{

              return this.dateConverter(res.json());})
            .catch((error:any)=>{
                return Observable.throw(error)||'server error';});
       }


 dateConverter(date){
    return new Date(date);
  }
```

You may have many api method like below.And you can call the above function to send request.

```
 testMethod(data){
      return this.postMethods('/setting/ChangePassword',data)
            .map(res=>{
              return res;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Do you mean that I have to change `return res.json()` with `JSON.parse(response, myReviver)`?

Comment: if you want to convert response  to json, `response.json()` work for you.JSON.parse will work as well..

Comment: I think so, since I need to use the reviver in order to convert the ASP.NET dates!

Comment: I updated the answer, you can type the converter code inside `dateConverter` function.I hope I got ur question clearly :)

Comment: Yes, it's really clear. I need to adjust it a little bit for my specific case, but it's been very useful. I'll mark it as accepted answer as soon as I try it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are wellcome.Good luck :)